# rewrite all .html extension and remove index in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How would I remove all .html extensions as well as any occurrences of index.html from a url string in Nginx

`http://www.mysite/index.html` to `http://www.mysite`
`http://www.mysite/articles/index.html` to `http://www.mysite/articles`
`http://www.mysite/contact.html` to `http://www.mysite/contact`
`http://www.mysite/foo/bar/index.html` to `http://www.mysite/foo/bar`

**EDIT:** Here is my conf file:

server {

```
    listen 80;

    server_name staging.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/staging.mysite.com;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/staging.mysite.com.log spiegle;


    #error_page 404         /404.html;
    #error_page 500 503     /500.html;


    rewrite ^(.*/)index\.html$ $1;
    rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $1;

    rewrite ^(.*/)index\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;

    location / {
            rewrite ^/about-us /about permanent                                                                                      
            rewrite ^/contact-us /contact permanent;  

            try_files  $uri.html  $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

}

Comment: I believe it's something like `rewrite index.html -;` and `rewrite .html$ -;` but I don't use nginx, so I'm not sure. Hopefully someone can wander along and write a good generic "Nginx Rewrite" Answer so we can have a close target. =]

Comment: The final path of "try_files" directives will create an internal redirect back to the index.html that you are wanting to redirect away from.  As far as I can tell from what you are doing, the final "path" should be set to "=404" to generate a 404 if the file doesn't exist.  Remove the first block of 2 rewrites so you just have the "permanent" ones, and then switch try_files to: `try_files  $uri.html "${uri}index.html" =404;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a rewrite (pass stripped URL to filesystem/backend without changing URL shown to client):

```
rewrite ^(.*/)index\.html$ $1;
rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $1;
```

**Alternatively** you can do a 301 redirect (client makes new request):

```
rewrite ^(.*/)index\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
```

Comment: That should go inside of a `location / {}`?

Comment: @Pardoner rewrite module's context is server, location and if. You can put them in any one of them. See manual for more http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

Comment: I get a 500 error when I use those :(

Comment: @Pardoner as Peter says they can be used there.  Regarding your config, those are two alternatives, not something you should put both of in.  If you are unsure which is appropriate for your application, I recommend the 301 redirect.

Comment: My comment above probably isn't clear.  What I mean is that you should only use 2 of my lines from my answer, not all 4.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't seem to work for me. I'm an apache guy who's making the switch, so this may not work 100% in all circumstances, but this seemed to work on my site (static html pages, just a test):

```
index index.html;
error_page 404 404.html;
rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $1;
try_files $uri.html $uri/ =404;
```

That is making this happen:

- url => file it's accessing
- domain.com/ => index.html
- domain.com/somepage => somepage.html
- domain.com/arandompage => 404.html

Hopefully this'll help out other confused former apache-ists.